# Can I check if a SOAP web service supports a certain WebMethod?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, soap

Our web services are distributed across different servers for various reasons (such as decreasing latency to the client), and they're not always all up-to-date. Rather than throwing an exception when a method *doesn't* exist because the particular web service is too old, it would be nicer if we could have the client check if the service responds to a given method before calling it, and otherwise disable the feature (or work around it).

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit test the web service to ensure its signatures don't break. When you write code that breaks the method signature, you'll know and can adjust the other applications accordingly.

Or just don't break the web services and publish them in a way that enable syou to version them. As in http://services.domain.com/MyService/V1.1/Service.asmx (for .NET) so that way your applications that use v1.1 won't break when you publish v1.2 and make breaking changes.

I would also check out using an internal UDDI server if it's really that big of a hasle to manage your web services. Using the Green Pages of UDDI will tell you what you want to know about the service.

Answer (score 2):

Get the WSDL (append ?wsdl to the URL) - you can parse that any way you like.

Answer (score 0):

When you are making a SOAP request you are just sending an HTTP request to a server. If the server understands it, it will respond with an HTTP 200 and some XML back, if it doesn't it will send you some error HTTP code (404, 500, ...)

There is no general way to ask for the existance of a "method" exposed by a web service. Try to use the WSDL exposed if it is automatic, or just try to use the "method" and check for an error in the response (you don't have to send an exception to the user...)

Also, I don't know if I understood you well, but you are thinking of quering the server twice, once to check if the method exists, and second to make the actual call it if it does? I would just check for the error if it doesn't, and proceed normally if it does.